# Win32 UI - Making a control expand as the parent expands

Tags: c++, c, winapi, user-interface

I'm using a resource editor to design my UI (resedit), however I cant find an option to tell it to keep the width of a control (listview) the same as its parent control (dialog) - so that when I resize the dialog also the listview resizes.

Can I do this through the resource file or do I need to call some C/C++ function?

Comment: GUI frameworks do this sort of stuff for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not automatic, you need to write some code to do it. Respond to the WM_SIZE message for the parent, determine how much the size changed, and resize the child by the same amount.

Functions that can resize a window are MoveWindow, SetWindowPos, and DeferWindowPos. DeferWindowPos is a lot more complicated but will result in a nicer update if there are many windows moving or changing size at the same time.

Comment: That's great, but I find myself having to move controls. What's the function to move these controls so that they are always aligned of the parent window dimensions?